# sql query/script for updating column values

Tags: mysql

I would like you to run a script where the existing fields
d1_image_url

should be changed from URL to image name
For example 
Following column contains

> abc.com/r_doc/58/567889.jpeg

i want only 567889.jpeg will print.
Note- image name will be unique for 10 thousand records.

I am trying with following update query but its not giving me unique image name.

> update cl_master set d1_image_url = substring_index('images/r_doc/58/567889.jpg','/',-1)

where  the cl_master is table name and d1_image_url is column name.

can any one give me solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your column name in substring function as parameter.

```
update cl_master set d1_image_url = substring_index(d1_image_url, '/', -1)
```

Comment: @ParagDeshmukh. glad to help

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
update cl_master set d1_image_url = SUBSTRING_INDEX(d1_image_url, '\\', -1)
```